# How to change the background of list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change the background of the listview so far i have tried this

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/myList"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"/>
```

but here the background doesn't seems to work.in fact its showing the back default back ground any idea how to achieve it .

Comment: What is in @color/white? Try using "@android:color/white".

Comment: @JaredBurrows not worked for me.

Comment: Can you post where this is being called? There must be something else wrong or changing the default behavior of the ListView?

Comment: @jared Burrowsyes i am showing this inside a alert dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/myList"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
```

If you using Custom Listview then in listitem latout define the background color.

listitem.xml// Say

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/artists_list_backgroundcolor"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  // Your Listitem widgets

</LinearLayout>
```

try like this..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the color of each listitem layout.

When you are setting up the adapter find the xml for the list item:

```
public class YourListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   /....Code for Adapter ...../

         public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {

            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.yourxml_listitem, null);

  /...rest of code for adapter .../
```

then edit the xml layout for your list item and add a background color to each list item, as I suspect you are setting up a different color / alternatively setup the color to transparent.

Comment: yes i dont know how to figure it out here in my case the listItems added dynamically at run time.if you have any idea please advice me.

Comment: sure setup the listitems background color at runtime.. using setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_red)...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it as a resource
    setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_red)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a selector fisrt.Like this,
list_bg.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/BackgroundColor" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Then set this as your background.

```
 <ListView
android:id="@+id/myList"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/list_bg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom ListAdapter for this list you can change the layout simply inside the getView() method of that class.

If you have not than You need to change these two parameters inside your custom theme

```
<item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>

  <item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@android:drawable/activated_background</item>
```

I did it inside the Custom List Adapter since I had a different requirement i.e. alternate background colors of list rows etc and it worked nicely. Never tried the second option but I belive it should work... see [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) for other alternatives for custom themes.

**EDIT**
We don't write style and theme declarations inside string.xml, that file is only for the string declarations. Create a file themes.xml inside the values folder, see following tutorials

1. [A simple tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/20/how-to-apply-a-custom-theme-to-an-android-application/)
2. [A Good tutorial](http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/android/android-create-custom-themes-for-your-apps/)
3. [The Best tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

See any of the above example.. Once theme is created you need to apply that theme to your Activity / Application inside android-manifiest file. You also need to extend any of the existing theme.

Comment: iam new to android do i need to write it inside the string.xml then i have to reference it in my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try like below lines.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="7dip"
                android:background="@drawable/list_white_bg" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="170dip"
                    android:divider="#e0e0e0"                    
                     android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
                    android:fadingEdge="none" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes its only changing the dividers color not the background color.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_height="fill_parent" first check if ur background is set correct else setBackgroundResource like this (make sure ur listview is on top of all others)

> listview.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);

If u would like ur own colors

`listview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Yellow);`

and in ur /res/strings.xml file

`<color name="Yellow">#FF0</color>`
for  more colors
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with that thing on android 2.2. I found that the best practice will be punting an image behind and setting the background as null.

```
<RelativerLayout 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/list_bg"/>

   <ListView
   android:id="@+id/myList"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:background="@null"/>

</RelativerLayout>
```

Comment: @user2295109 This is different question, try [this](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php) tutorial it will help you.It's not that simple...